# .htaccess specified url with base file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory `site` and its sub-folder and files in it.
It also contain a `.htacess` and below is the code

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?cc=$1
```

so my below url will is effective and working good.

```
http://localhost/site/sweetinc
```

And below code in `index.php` below

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['cc']) and !empty($_GET['cc'])) {
    echo $_GET['cc'];
} else {
    die("Sorry wrong code");
}
?>
```

And this is working good.

Now, i want to access or display all files as normally

```
http://localhost/site/sweetinc/home.php
http://localhost/site/sweetinc/test.php
```

`home.php` and `test.php` are located in `site` directory. And if it redirects to other sub-folders then it should
be visible like

```
http://localhost/site/sweetinc/sub-folder1/test3.php
```

Is this possible, as I am working seperating a group using seperate directory using `.htaccess` and considering all files in `site` directory as `base files`

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your update. The folder /sweetinc/ does not exist, but you want people to use the url /site/sweetinc/ to show the files that are actually in /site/, right? Then what does the index.php?cc= have to do with it? Do you want to use that when the requested url (like /site/sweetinc/something) does not exist, so that it then shows index.php?cc=something, but not if the url _does_ exist? Do I get that right?

Comment: Yes!, `/sweetinc/` does not exist and i want to show all files are in `/site/sweetinc/`

Actually i want  `index.php?cc=` to know the `fakedirectoryname` ie `sweetinc`

Comment: So it will have url likes

`http://localhost/site/company1/home.php`

`http://localhost/site/company2/home.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here (if I understand your question correctly) is that you don't want the rewrite rule to be in effect when you're trying to reach a file that actually exists, right?

In that case, just before your  `RewriteRule`, add these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That way, the rewriterule only takes effect when the url (/site/sweetinc for example) does not really exist on the server. If it does (/site/sweetinc/home.php) the rewriterule is skipped and the file is shown.

(`-f` checks if the filename exists, `-d` checks if the directory exists, so /home/sweetinc/somedir/ should work too)

***Update based on updated question***
You need two separate rules for this. First of all, if the /sweetinc/ directory in the url is used, refer them to the /site/ folder:

```
RewriteRule ^sweetinc/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Then, if the file does not actually exist, let the index.php handle it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cc=$1 [L]
```

Some examples:

I have the following files in my files subdomain:

- /index.php (which has the same content as yours does, so it reads out ?cc=
- /circle3.PNG
- /the .htaccess with the above rules

http://files.litso.com/sweetinc/hello shows the index.php that echoes "hello"
http://files.litso.com/sweetinc/circle3.PNG shows the actual file in /

(note, I don't have a /sweetinc/ directory, it's all faked)

Comment: I have updated the  question with an image for better understanding.

Comment: but its not working when i change `sweetinc` to `abc` and note: `sweetinc` or `abc` are changeable automatically it can be later `xyz`

Comment: In that case, replace `^sweetinc/` in the first rule with `^([^/]+)/`

Comment: you mean to say like this `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1 [L]` and this is not working